# Map different entities to the same table, always saving as one entity and loading depending on the context

Tags: hibernate, mapping, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to make my domain clear by using different entities in different contexts. At the database, these entities will be persisted in the same table. I have the following class hierarchy:

- an abstract class called Person (with id and name);
- the User class, which extends Person (with loginName, password and role);
- the Vendor class, which also extends Person (with a set of deals);

This way, I use the Vendor class in the sales context and the User class in the login context. The problem is that every person is inserted into the system by users's administration context. This way, every row in the database has the discriminator column with the value 'user'. I would like to be able to use load the data as Vendor instances (when working in the sales context) and use it to persist a Sale object (which will have a Vendor instance), but in the database, it refers to the Users table.

In short: at the database I have the user table, which in my domain can represent two entities: User and Vendor. They always must be persisted as users, but the must to be loaded based on it's context. How can I map this in hibernate, since using the subclass element makes every instance to be loaded as User (as they are saved as users) ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, this is not possible using inheritance, a `Person` instance cannot be a `User` **and** a `Vendor` with Hibernate, a `Person` is either a `User` or (exclusive) a `Vendor`.

What you could do is map a `Person` to multiple `Role` and have `User` and `Vendor` extend `Role`.